# How to tap by coordinates using appium in python

Tags: android, python-2.7, coordinates, appium

I got this error while attempting to tap by coordinates using appium in python:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'id'

This is the code that I used:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction

caps = {}
caps["deviceName"] = "NVWCE6YSV47TGM8S"
caps["platformName"] = "Android"
caps["appPackage"] = "com.gradrix.quicklaunch"
caps["appActivity"] = "com.gradrix.quicklaunch.MainActivity"
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", caps)

time.sleep(5)
TouchAction(driver).tap([(104, 255)]).perform()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: You have an excellent [mcve]. I'm not sure why people are trying to close this.

Comment: Try `TouchAction(driver).tap(x=104, y=255).perform()`. `tap` expects two keywords and not a list.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters I changed `.tap(x=104, y=255)` instead `.tap([(104, 255)])` and I got: KeyError: 'touchAction'.

Answer (score 6):

It is working for me like this:

```
# None - don't know why is needed but as I want to tap at coordinates and not an element, is None
# 104  - X coordinate
# 255  - Y coordinate
# 1    - this is the time of the tap action
TouchAction(driver).tap(None, 104, 255, 1).perform()
```

Hope it helps and you get it working

Comment: Cannot be 100% sure but it seems that the device is expecting the size of a real finger to be tapped. Meaning that when I was trying to be very near the top of the screen, tapping at y=10 or 50 px the tap would not work. But when the tap would be at around ~200px then it would work fine (at a screen of >2000px height). Perhaps also I was tapping the status bar of the android when y was so small. Anyone knows how to calculate the height of the status bar of Android ?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

to

```
from appium import webdriver
```